# PNG files won't be displayed but JPEG and GIF work fine on Apache/CentOS

Tags: apache, png, centos

I have a website that is running on CentOS 6 and Apache 2. If I try to load any page with PNG images in it the image is shown as a broken link - I get the same issue if I go directly to the image file in the browser. I have tried this in Chrome, Firefox and Safari all with the same results so I am guessing it is server side.

Looking at the apache logs I can see that the file is being served up and returning a http 200 code.

There is an entry for PNG in mime.types and adding the following to httpd.conf makes no difference:

```
AddType image/png .png
```

I have also removed the .htaccess to ensure that nothing in there could be affecting it to no avail.

This happens for all PNG files which have the same permissions as the JPEGs that work fine.

Can't think what else to try, any ideas?

Comment: Older versions of IE didn't support PNG.  Try downloading the PNGs with wget

Comment: This is a mac so nothing to do with IE and as I said above the access_log shows the file is being served correctly and there is nothing in the error_log.

Comment: If you've solved the problem, the post the solution as an answer, or delete the question